# How do I prioritize material deliveries?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In [Oxygen Not Included](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_Not_Included) I have the problem that sometimes a high priority task will get blocked by a material delivery that is apparently less prioritized.

In other words, I want to build a building and it is set to maximum priority, but nevertheless dupes are doing other lower priority tasks and the reason for this is that the building is "awaiting a material delivery". I cannot see any way to prioritize the material delivery. What I want to do is prioritize the delivery the same as the building.

Comment: Did you actually prioritize the jobs in the priorities menu, or did you only change the 0-9 slider on the object? These are two separate settings.

Comment: @Flater I only prioritized the 9 on the build slider.

Comment: There's your issue. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your response in the comments suggested the source of the issue:

> Did you actually prioritize the jobs in the priorities menu, or did you only change the 0-9 slider on the object? These are two separate settings
>
> *I only prioritized the 9 on the build slider.*

The 0-9 sub-priorities only change priority *within the same job*. For example, if your dupe decides "I'm going to build something", he'll look at the 0-9 slider of the blueprints and pick the one with the highest sub-priority.

However, this doesn't prioritize different jobs. That is done via the priority panel (accessed with the J key). In this screen, you can decide every dupe's job priorities ("should I build first and clean second, or the other way around?").

It is only when a dupe has decided which job to do from the priority panel, that they then evaluate which sub-priorirty takes precedence.

[More info in the wiki here](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Priority).

*I won't go into the details of job prioritization logic, the wiki is much better for this level of detail.*

Comment: Gofer is the job you're interested in for your Duplicant, and prioritising Supply.